# Strange error with a For loop in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

```
int main(void)
{
  const char * attributeNames = "StrDexConIntWisCha";
  int characterValues[7] = {0};
  int characterBonuses[7] = {0};
  characterStats(characterValues);
}

void characterStats(int * characterValues)
{
  int numberOfDice = 4; int diceType = 6;
  int x = 1;//because characterValues[0] is level.
  printf("What is your level? > ");
  scanf("%d",&characterValues[0]);
  printf("Current Level [%d]", characterValues[0]);
  printf("Rolling stats.\n");
  for(x; x <= numberOfDice; x++)
  {
    characterValues[x] = diceRoll(diceType);//rolling a d6
  }
}

int diceRoll(int diceType)
{
  int numberOfDice = 4;
  int x,y,z = 0;
  int diceResult, finalValue, lowestResult = 0;
  int diceRoll[4] = {0};
  for(x; x <= numberOfDice; x++)
  {
    printf("%d", diceRoll[x]);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create a function that will roll a 6-sided dice, 4 times, for a character generator for dungeons and dragons. The last for loop in `diceRoll`, doesn't appear to execute, it just skips it over and I don't understand why. At the moment, I'm just testing to see if everything works before adding in the `rand()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
int x,y,z = 0;
```

Here you only initialized `z` to `0`, leaving `x` and `y` uninitialized, and then in the `for` loop:

```
for(x; x <= numberOfDice; x++)
```

Again, `x` is not initialized.

Comment: Ah, couldn't believe I missed that. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You should always initialize your loop counter in the `for` loop:

```
for(x=0; x<numberOfDice; x++)
```

and too, notice I used `<` not `<=`; a loop from 0 will always do *n* iterations from 0 for `<n` (using `<=` will do *n+1*). Looping from 0 to *n-1* is idiomatic in all C-like languages since it tends to match things like indexes an an array being iterated, or pointer manipulations, which are all 0-based.

Comment: Just realized that when fixing it up. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

either make

```
int x=0,y,z=0;
```

or make

```
for(x = 0; x <= numberOfDice; x++)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you'd come along 8 hours later and just repeat the same information as the existing answers?